# <apex:input type="date" /> Not displaying date picker in Internet Explorer

Tags: apex, visualforce, date, date-picker, internet-explorer

```
 <apex:input type="date" styleClass="input-text-center" value="{! data.offerDate }" 
                                        rendered="{! IF( AND( data.isField = true, data.isDateField = true ) , true, false ) }" />
```

The above code is displaying datepicker in chrome but not in IE. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a known issue, some browsers do not show `datepicker` when using `apex:input` tag. You will need to find alternative for this.

Here is the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206142&language=en_US&type=1) which says this

You can either use `inputField` if date is a standard/custom object property or try using `jQuery` datepicker.

Comment: When I use inputField its showing error like : Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!data.offerDate}'.  <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: And also jquery supporting for inputfield

Comment: As I said, if its not a `sObject` property, u cannot use `inputField`. See jQuery datepicker example [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82154/issue-with-jquery-datepicker-in-visualforce-page)

Comment: Thank you  Jain. I will post my finding once I Done with it

Comment: <apex:input styleClass="input-text-center"  value="{! data.offerDate }" size="10" id="demo" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false); "/>                            this code is working but it is  showing timestamp in the EDIT mode.

Comment: Can you add a new question and describe the issue in detail, with the entire code.